# I changed my username and now I cannot play online

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't understand this and I'm now worried as I have donated to a lot of servers and I don't want to lose this account. On the launcher it says my new username but when I log on it says "Account not Authenticated with minecraft.net" and "Non-Valid Username".

How can I regain the ability to use my account online?

Answer (score 14):

It's caused by remaining logged in after changing your name. Not everything is updated.

You need to open the Minecraft launcher, log out, and log back in again (i.e. you need to enter your user and password again). This should fix it.

Comment: Ugh. I don't know who suggested that edit but **please stop everything you are doing**.